# MySQL only returning one row using one table

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, where-clause, having-clause

[image: My table]

I want to find the total room cost and total stay cost (room and expenses), and display the ones that are above $50 for total cost.

I wrote this query:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, expenses, room_rate,
SUM(stays_num*room_rate) as 'total_room_cost',
SUM((stays_num*room_rate)+expenses) as 'total_stay_cost'
FROM assign1.customer
WHERE 'total_stay_cost' < 50
```

The only one that pops up is Kristoff Kurn. Justin Hackman should also come up because he has also spent more than 50 in total.
[image: Only one query comes up.]

Comment: You want to `GROUP BY`

Comment: `'total_stay_cost' < 50` makes no sense, you're comparing a string with a number (and the operator is contradicting your requirements, you want `total_stay_cost > 50`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you select normal columns and aggregate functions, you need to use `GROUP BY` to tell over which you want the aggregate calculation to be performed.

Secondly, the conditions that affect the aggregate function results, should be put in a HAVING-clause (sort of a where-clause for group by).

So you query would look like this:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, expenses, room_rate,
  SUM(stays_num*room_rate) as 'total_room_cost',
  SUM((stays_num*room_rate)+expenses) as 'total_stay_cost'
FROM assign1.customer
GROUP BY first_name, last_name, expenses, room_rate
HAVING total_stay_cost < 50
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query has multiple issues:

- don't use single quotes for identifiers! They stand for literal strings.
- you can't reuse an alias defined in the `select` clause in the `where` clause (the latter is evaluated *before* the former).
- the aggregation part is off: either missing a `group by` clause, or you should not be using aggrgate functions in the `select` clause

If you want one result per row that satisfies the condition, then:

```
select c.*,
    stays_num * room_rate as total_room_cost,
    stays_num * room_rate + expenses as total_stay_cost
from assign1.customer c
where stays_num * room_rate + expenses > 50
```

If you want, say, one row per customer, then:

```
select c.customer_id, c.first_name, c.last_name,
    sum(stays_num * room_rate) as total_room_cost,
    sum(stays_num * room_rate + expenses) as total_stay_cost
from assign1.customer c
group by c.customer_id
having total_stay_cost > 50
```